# Finding the sqrt of a number

Tags: java, loops, while-loop, do-while, square-root

So i am just trying to write a program that lets the user enter a number that is bigger than 10 , and finding the sqrt of this number. But i should do the square root operation many times in order to make the sqrt of the entered number less than 4. After that, i should print the initial value of the sqrt of the number and the number of times that the square root operation was done. I don't seem to find what is wrong with the program that i wrote. Can you please help me with it?

```
   public static void main(String[] args) {
   int counter = 1 ; 
   double sqrt  , sqrt1 , n ; 



   Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);
   do{
       System.out.print("Enter any number : ");
       n = input.nextInt();

   }while(n < 10);

   sqrt = Math.sqrt(n);

 while (sqrt > 4){
     sqrt1 = Math.sqrt(sqrt);
     counter++ ;
 }

   System.out.println("The square root of the entered number is : " + sqrt);
   System.out.println("The square root operation was made : " + counter + " time(s)");


}
```

}

Comment: Hint: do you change the value of the variable `sqrt` after is has been set initially?

Comment: This is where stepping through your code with your debugger should be the fastest way to solve this problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Look at this loop:

```
while (sqrt > 4){
    sqrt1 = Math.sqrt(sqrt);
    counter++ ;
}
```

You are checking if `sqrt` is larger than `4`, but you are not modifying the value of `sqrt` inside the loop, so `sqrt > 4` will forever remain `true` and the loop will keep on iterating forever.

Comment: Thats why you should never name your variables like `sqrt` and `sqrt1`, it's very error prone and hard to debug. Instead of that rename `sqrt1` to something meaningful like `returnedSqrt`